# How to put symbol in specific place and skip it in normal tex

Tags: rendering

I need to put some symbol/paragraph in specific (x,y) place.

How I can do it?

Is possible to skip this in normal text?

Text is big but in specific place i put some words.

Comment: Try the [`textpos` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos)

Comment: Also try the background package.

Comment: Textpos not omitted /spipped my text

Comment: It's not clear (at least to me) what you mean with "skip this in normal text". Can you please explain in a little more detail?

Answer (score 7):

As Andrew pointed out, the `textpos` package is designed for this purpose.

This is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showboxes,absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage[step=1cm,arrows=false,firstcolor=white,secondcolor=white]{pagegrid}

\begin{document}

\begin{textblock*}{3cm}(7cm,4cm)
  \raggedright
  \Huge My text
\end{textblock*}

\end{document}
```

which gives the following result (the image is the left upper portion of the page):

[image]

In the example I've loaded the `pagegrid` package just to show a 1cm x 1cm grid needed to see the result (you don't need it at all).

As you can see the box is exactly positioned in the point 7cm x 4cm of the page, as specified by the argument `(7cm,4cm)` of the `textblock*` environment.

When you're sure that the box containing your text (as specified by the argument `{3cm}`) is OK, you can remove the option `showboxes` when loading the package, unless you want to see the box margins.

For more info, have a look at the [`textpos` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/textpos/textpos.pdf).

### EDIT

Regarding your comment, you can define a new command `\putglyph` as follows

```
\newcommand{\putglyph}[3]{%
  \begin{textblock*}{1cm}(#2cm,#3cm)
    \raggedright
    \Huge #1
  \end{textblock*}
}
```

and then use it in this way

```
\putglyph{M}{7}{4}
```

where the first argument is the glyph to position, the second is the X coordinate and the third the Y coordinate.

Alternatively, you can define it as:

```
\newcommand{\putglyph}[1]{\tempglyph(#1)}
\def\tempglyph(#1,#2,#3){%
  \begin{textblock*}{1cm}(#2cm,#3cm)
    \raggedright
    \Huge #1
  \end{textblock*}
}
```

and use it with comma-separated arguments:

```
\putglyph{M,7,4}
```

Comment: is any alternative to textblock* i must put only one glyph

Comment: @Witold see the edited answer