# How to position text on a page exactly?

Tags: positioning

I have a preset background picture which is essentially a role playing character sheet without any text on it.

I need to position a lot of information on it and it has to line up exactly with the background image.

This is what i have got so far. I assume i could go for a tikz picture but i am not sure i can stretch that to encompass the whole page.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{wallpaper}

\begin{document}

\ThisCenterWallPaper{1}{Page1.png}
\mbox{NAME}

\end{document}
```

How can i set text at exact positions relative to a full page A4 background image.

Comment: Have you seen http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24663/how-to-place-a-floating-text-box-at-a-specified-location-in-page-coordinates?rq=1

Comment: I never used it so far, but have a look on the `textpos` package (it's on TeXLive/CTAN)

Comment: May [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126829/27635) of mine help?

Comment: If the image requires the complete page, then perhaps this answer is also useful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page.  Likewise, there is this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108374/how-can-i-construct-a-page-layout-with-framed-boxes

Comment: Also \tikz[remember picture,overlay] gives you access to anchor points like (current page.north west) which is the absolute top left corner of the page.

Answer (score 1):

The LateX `picture` environment puts things in a known place.  If you put it in the page header then it puts it in the same known place on every page.